# Parse check if user already exist

Tags: parsing, parse-platform

I already made reseting password, but still need something more. I mean that if user add an email to text field and push button send, he gets back alert if it is equal to username on Parse. If not, show alert that not. Any ideas?
Thank you

**ForgottenViewController.h**

```
-(IBAction)logoutPressed:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *maill;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityLog;

@end
```

**ForgottenViewController.m**

```
#import "ForgottenViewController.h"
#import "SignUpViewController.h"

@interface ForgottenViewController ()
@end

@implementation ForgottenViewController
@synthesize maill;



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




 -(IBAction)logoutPressed:(id)sender {
     PFQuery *query=[PFUser query];
     [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:maill];
     [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
         if (object) {
             NSString *myString = maill.text;
             [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:myString];
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Great" message:@"Now check your email. You will be able to change your password right now." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [_activityLog stopAnimating];
         }else{
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Sorry, but the email is not registred." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [_activityLog stopAnimating];
         }
     }];}







@end
```

Comment: What is currently happens when the user presses button their email is already registered with an account on Parse?

Comment: Right now, it is showing all the time first alert even if I put to the text field email, which is not equal to parse string "username".

Comment: I have also almost the same problem in my RegisterController. Don`t know how to set if else, using PFQuery to check is user already exist. If he exist I want to show alert that the username is already taken. It is the same problem like this if else PFQuery, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the whereKey search is case sensitive.  Make sure that you typed in the email exactly as you stored it.  Parse suggests that you use canonical fields in situations like this where you store the email all lowercase and a separate email that you show to the user.

I should have see this the first time.  The variable `mail` is a UITextField and not an NSString.  Try passing `mail.text` instead of just `mail` to the query.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, It does not show me anything. App crash after I clic on button clic. I am not sure, if this line [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
         if (object) {        is possible to use.

Comment: Instead of `PFQuery *query=[PFUser query]` try `PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];`

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?  What is the error in Xcode?

Comment: main.m         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
0x1740d3b:  xorl   %eax, %eax

Comment: In Xcode on the breakpoint pane click on the + at the bottom and add the "Add Exception Breakpoint..." and run it again to find out where the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:maill]; this line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48630/discussion-between-stephen-johnson-and-milan1111)

Answer (score 3):

For Android Users : In case if anyone is facing the same issue

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();     
        query.whereEqualTo("email", "demo11@gmail.com");

        query.countInBackground(new CountCallback(){

            @Override
            public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e == null) {
                    if(count==0){
                  //Username doesnt exit
                    }                           
                }               
            }

        });
```